# Using Ajax add Json data to table without refreshing the page in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I have Order table and OrderNotes table. OrderNotes have foreign key OrderID in it. I want to use AJAX to insert JSON data into my OrderNotes table. Below is my code

Here is asps file that contains Ajax which

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Orders/Index",
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#divContent").html(data);
                        $('.dropdown').hover(function () {
                            var $text = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nearest").text();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "OrderNotes/Index?orderId=" + $text + "",
                            type: 'POST',
                            success: function (data) {
                                $(".orderContent").html(data);
                                function CreateOrderNotes() {
                                    var Bywho = $("#By").val();
                                    var NoteBy = $("#Note").val();
                                    var OrderIdgiven = $("#OrderID").val();
                                    var $text = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nearest").text();
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        URL: "OrderNotes/Create",
                                        data: JSON.stringify({
                                            By: Bywho, Note: NoteBy, OrderID: OrderIdgiven
                                        }),
                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                        success: function (result) {
                                            $("#table").append("<tr><td>" +
                                                result.OrderNotesID + "</td><td>" +
                                                result.By + "</td><td>" +
                                                result.Note + "</td><td>" +
                                                result.OrderID + "</td></tr>")
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });


                    });
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
    <div id="divContent" class="container">
    </div>
```

Order Controller and view is not important so have excluded those files.

OrderNotes View and controller

OrderNotes Controller

```
namespace Ordernotes.Controllers
{
    public class OrderNotesController : Controller
    {
        private OrderDbContext db = new OrderDbContext();
        // GET: OrderNotes
        public ActionResult Index(int orderid)
        {
            List<OrderNote> OrderNotesforOrderId = new List<OrderNote>();
            if (db.Orders != null)
            {
                List<OrderNote> notesforeachorder = db.OrderNotes.Where(m => m.OrderID == orderid).ToList();
                foreach (var ev in notesforeachorder)
                {
                    OrderNotesforOrderId.Add(ev);
                }
            }
            return PartialView(OrderNotesforOrderId);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(OrderNote orderNote)
        {
            OrderDbContext entities = new OrderDbContext();
            var notes = new OrderNote();
            notes.By =orderNote.By;
            notes.Note = orderNote.Note;
            notes.OrderID = orderNote.OrderID;
            entities.OrderNotes.Add(notes);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            return Json(notes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

OrderNotes Index

```
@model IEnumerable<Ordernotes.Models.OrderNote>
<table class="table" id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderNoteID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Note)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.By)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderID)
        </th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderNoteID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.By)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderID)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
<div class="notesfooter div-table">
    @Html.Partial("Create",new Ordernotes.Models.OrderNote())
</div>
```

OrderNotes Create

```
@model Ordernotes.Models.OrderNote



<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.By, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.By, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Note, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrderID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <a id="savesnotes" onclick="CreateOrderNotes()" class="btn btn-default" >Save</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Only Ajax third call is not working. Can't figure out how to send JSON data and what parameter to pass in Create in OrderNotes Create function.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Actually I have to finish this assignment by morning. That's why I added Urgent ? Can you help regarding the problem ?

Comment: If you read the link I provided, you'll find the community regards "urgent" requests as a rudeness that carries the strong assumption that question authors can place social obligations upon their readers. We are very much of the view that it is unfair for you to try, since we have our own pressures and deadlines. Once this has been pointed out, it is really inappropriate to carry on begging. If this is for an academic assignment, I suggest you contact your tutor, explain the reason for the lateness, and request a time extension.

Comment: (I suggest also that you do not rely on getting answers to this question, and try other things while you wait. You may not receive an answer in the timescale you are hoping for).